# Plot multiple columns of pandas DataFrame on the bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I am using the following code to plot a bar-chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pls 
my_df.plot(x='my_timestampe', y='col_A', kind='bar') 
plt.show()
```

The plot works fine. However, I want to improve the graph by having 3 columns: 'col_A', 'col_B', and 'col_C' all on the plot. Like in the example figure below:

[image]

I would like the `col_A` displayed in blue above x-axis, `col_B` in red below x-axis, and `col_C` in green above x-axis. Is this something possible in matplotlib? How do I make changes to plot all the three columns? Thanks!

Answer (score 182, accepted):

**Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.1`, `matplotlib 3.6.2`**

### Sample Data and Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2022)  # creates a consistent sample
y = np.random.rand(10,4)
y[:,0]= np.arange(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["X", "A", "B", "C"])

     X         A         B         C
0  0.0  0.499058  0.113384  0.049974
1  1.0  0.486988  0.897657  0.647452
2  2.0  0.721135  0.831353  0.827568
3  3.0  0.957044  0.368044  0.494838
4  4.0  0.619429  0.977530  0.096433
5  5.0  0.292499  0.298675  0.752473
6  6.0  0.523737  0.864436  0.388843
7  7.0  0.475181  0.564672  0.349429
8  8.0  0.037820  0.794270  0.357883
9  9.0  0.914509  0.372662  0.964883
```

Several columns can be plotted at once by supplying a list of column names to the `y=` parameter in [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
ax = df.plot(x="X", y=["A", "B", "C"], kind="bar", rot=0)
```

This will produce a graph where bars are grouped.

[image]

```py
ax = df.plot(x="X", y=["A", "B", "C"], kind="bar", rot=0, stacked=True)
_ = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

This will produce a graph where bars are stacked.

[image]

---

In order to have them overlapping, you would need to call `.plot` several times, and supply the first returned axes to the `ax=` parameter of the subsequent plots.

```py
ax = df.plot(x="X", y="A", kind="bar", rot=0)
df.plot(x="X", y="B", kind="bar", ax=ax, color="C2", rot=0)
df.plot(x="X", y="C", kind="bar", ax=ax, color="C3", rot=0)

plt.show()
```

**This will produce a graph where bars are layered, which is neither a standard or recommended implementation** because larger values plotted in a later group will cover smaller values, as can be seen at `x=9.0`, where `C=0.964883` covers, `A=0.914509` and `B=0.372662`. **Data plotted in this way is likely to be misinterpreted.**

[image]

This plot only makes sense if the highest values are those from the first column plotted for all bars. This seems to be the case in the desired output from the question. Otherwise I would not recommend using this kind of plot and instead either use a stacked plot or the grouped bars from the first solution here. One could experiment with transparency (`alpha`) and see if the latter solution gives an appealing result.

Answer (score 22):

Although the accepted answer works fine, since [v0.21.0rc1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v0.21.0rc1) it gives a warning

> UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name

Instead, one can do

```
df[["X", "A", "B", "C"]].plot(x="X", kind="bar")
```

Comment: As per a deleted comment by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, the `UserWarning` was never reproducible, and it certainly isn't reproducible now. The canonical approach to provide columns to [`.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) is to pass a list to the `y=` parameter, as shown in the accepted answer.