# Plotting a bar chart using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: one is names of sports and another is number of athletes in each of them. I tried plotting a bar graph using:

```
ax = div1[['Sport','Athletes']].plot(kind='bar', title="abcd", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
```

[Data used to plot bar chart][1]

But I got the following error:

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-29052602d3cd> in <module>()
----> 1 ax = div1[['Sport','Athletes']].plot(kind='bar', title="abcd", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   3772                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   3773                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 3774                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   3775     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   3776 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2641                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   2642                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 2643                  **kwds)
   2644 
   2645 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   2468         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   2469 
-> 2470     plot_obj.generate()
   2471     plot_obj.draw()
   2472     return plot_obj.result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in generate(self)
   1039     def generate(self):
   1040         self._args_adjust()
-> 1041         self._compute_plot_data()
   1042         self._setup_subplots()
   1043         self._make_plot()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
   1148         if is_empty:
   1149             raise TypeError('Empty {0!r}: no numeric data to '
-> 1150                             'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
   1151 
   1152         self.data = numeric_data

TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Could someone please tell where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance. 
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeIXz.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: plot multiple columns of pandas data frame on the bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128467/matplotlib-plot-multiple-columns-of-pandas-data-frame-on-the-bar-chart)

Comment: Your numbers are stored as strings, need `div1['Athletes'] = pd.to_numeric(div1.Athletes.str.replace(',', ''))` before the plot

Comment: Thanks! It worked!